# icon in JButton is not shown at the running of the program, what could be?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I'm training with Java, especially with GUI (Swing & AWT), but I'm having a problem with icon in JButton. The image isn't shown, to make that visible I must resize the window, how could I do?

Here is the code:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements WindowListener, KeyListener, ActionListener, FocusListener, MouseListener{

private final String APPLICATION_NAME = "GUI";
private final String APPLICATION_VERSION = "0.0.1";

private final JButton btnCiao;

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

public MainWindow(){
        super();
        this.setTitle(APPLICATION_NAME + " " + APPLICATION_VERSION);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.addWindowListener(this); 
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setLocation((int)(dimension.getWidth()/2-getWidth()/2), (int)(dimension.getHeight()/2-getHeight()/2));
        this.setVisible(true);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        add(panel);
        btnCiao = new JButton("WAU");
        panel.add(btnCiao);

        JButton imageButton = new JButton();
        try{
            Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Nike.jpg"));
            Image img2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Adidas.jpg"));
            imageButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
            imageButton.setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
        } catch(IOException ex){}

        // to remove the border
        imageButton.setBorder(null);
        panel.add(imageButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to call `revalidate()` on the frame in the end of that function.

Comment: The image is located in the same package of .java files

Comment: The problem shouldn't be on the files location, because it works if you resize your JFrame.

Comment: revalidate() works , I didn't know about this method! Is it a good way to solve this kind of problems?

Comment: I think your problem is similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890898/jframe-jlabel-image-refresh-only-if-i-resize-the-window Give it a try.

Comment: I think it should also work if you only call the `repaint()` method.

Comment: No reapaint(); doesn't work

Comment: Write that as answer, and I'll mark your!

Comment: `setVisible` _after_ adding your components then you won't have to worry about revalidate

Comment: using 'setVisible' instad of 'validate()' doesn't show the icon, also if I remove 'setBorder(null)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `revalidate()` method on your `JFrame` after adding the `JButton`.

When you change the attribute of a component that would affect its appearance, you should call this method.

[Difference between validate(), revalidate() and invalidate() in Swing GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510125/difference-between-validate-revalidate-and-invalidate-in-swing-gui)